# How to modify the background color a little more

Tags: html, css

In the below image I am trying to make the background color stop at the red line. How can I do that?

I have tried to add bottom 50px or something but if I add more than 2 settings to the background it won't work any more.

I can go top and left bottom and right whatever combination but maximum 2, when I add the third it won't work.

[image: green background]

```css
.div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 35%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 11%;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.pdiv2 {
  font-family: futuraptbook;
  font-size: 100px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin: 35px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#54B3A1, #54B3A1);
  background-position: left 220px top 165px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.btn1 {
  font-family: futuraptdemi;
  margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
  width: 188px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f34213;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div2">
  <p class="pdiv2">DRINK LESS, DRINK BETTER.</p>
  <form action="#">
    <button class="btn1">FIND OUT MORE</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The space you see is the `descender space` for letters like `q, p, g, j, y` which require space below the baseline. The background-color applies to the entire line height which included that descender space. There is no easy and responsive solution than to hard-code the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically how I achieved this in the end as it was not possible with background: I have made another div with the exact same size as I wanted the background to be, set its background a the green color, given it `position: relative`, and negative `margin` so it will overlap with the text and given the text higher `z-index`

Comment: Could you please add the code so that others don't have to process your text and imagine the result?